# Bitbucket migration to Github with TAG's for an existing migrated repo

Tags: git, tags, migration, bitbucket

The task is to migrate an existing Bitbucket repo to Github. The migration has taken place but without ANY tags. The Bitbucket repo has many many tags but these are missing from the Github repo. Any steps that I can follow to remedy this?

I'd really appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps you need to follow to migrate Git Repo with History(All branches/tags/History)

1. git clone --mirror ssh://source_git_url.git
2. cd folder >> cd to cloned folder
3. create the new repo in Target GIT with same git name(preferred to avoid confusion)
4. git remote add bitbucket https://userid@bitbucket_host.target_url/target_git_url.git
5. git push https://userid@bitbucket_host.target_url/target_git_url.git --mirror
6. Done please verify the target git repo

Note: On point 4, i used bitbucket if target is bitbucket otherwise origin will work.

Answer (score 0):

> Step 1: Create Github repository

First, create a new repository on Github.com. It’s important to keep the repository empty, e.g. don’t check option Initialize this repository with a README when creating the repository.

> Step 2: Move existing content

Next, we need to fill the Github repository with the content from our Bitbucket repository:

1. Check out the existing repository from Bitbucket:

   `$ git clone https://USER@bitbucket.org/USER/PROJECT.git`
2. Add the new Github repository as upstream remote of the repository checked out from Bitbucket:

   `$ cd PROJECT`

   `$ git remote add upstream https://github.com:USER/PROJECT.git`
3. Push all branches (below: just master) and tags to the Github repository:

   `$ git push upstream master`
   `$ git push --tags upstream`

> Step 3: Clean up old repository

Finally, we need to ensure that developers don’t get confused by having two repositories for the same project. Here is how to delete the Bitbucket repository:
Double check that the Github repository has all content
Go to the web interface of the old Bitbucket repository
Select menu option `Setting > Delete repository`
Add the URL of the new Github repository as redirect URL
With that, the repository completely settled into its new home at Github. Let all the developers know!
That’s it.

***EDITED***

**To fetch tags:**

```
git fetch --tags
```

**To push tags to remote repo:**

```
git push origin --tags
```

Comment: This works good if I'm starting from scratch. Here, one developer has already migrated the repo from Bitbucket to Github without any of the TAG's. In this current scenario how can I get the Github repo to have all the TAG's from the bitbucket repo without having to delete the github repo and restarting the process which you've mentioned above.